# Firebase update a lot of children value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Suppose I have 10000 children in "post" each node contain children "username". If "userA" was added 6000 in 10000 of data. How can I update "userA" in every node in "post"

[image: firebase]

Comment: With your structure you cant do it.

Comment: do you want to change the username from "userA" to another username?

Comment: Thanks @J.Doe Can you give example structure for this purpose ?

Comment: Thanks @faruk Yes, when user update their username it's should update all  post node that ownerd by this user

Comment: @LIPONEF Pipiks example is the one you should use

Comment: @LIPONEF Checkout my answer

Answer (score 2):

You need to know all user posts.

You need a structure like that :

```
root
 |
 +-- posts
 |     |
 |     +-- $postId
 |           |
 |           +-- text: $text
 |           |
 |           +-- username: $username
 |
 +-- userPosts
 |     |
 |     +-- $userId
 |           |
 |           +-- $postId: true
```

With this structure you can retrieve all posts id for a user and update posts.

Comment: Thanks Pipiks, If i put UID instead of username. when i query each post i get UID to query username from another node (ex. root->users->uid->username="userA"). Compare with your given structure which one is better because someone tell me that my given example can waste your firebase traffic cost.

Comment: You don't have to change your post strucure just add userPosts or do a request like that `postsRef.orderByChild("username").equalsTo("userA")` like in @jorge answer

Comment: @Pipiks in the posts data, you should put the userId too.. I'm calling it bydirectional relation in nosql

Comment: @Pipiks I found this link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i1n9Kw3AORw&feature=youtu.be  this is a good one solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase if NOSQL schema , you can't apply straight queries on it. You need to apply iteration on all nodes and update if username is "userA"

Comment: @LIPONEF sample codes are posted below in some answers, you can modify them as per your need.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change text from *helloA* to *hello I'm A*, for example, code something like:

```
    DatabaseReference postReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");

    postReference.orderByChild("username").equalsTo("userA")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                        for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            data.getRef().child("text").setValue("hello I'm A");
```

So you have a dataSnapshot with every post with username equals to userA and you can iterate over it and change those posts

Answer (score 0):

The question is about updating field username.
My suggestion is create a temporary hashMap for update values. So it will only update once for all posts.

The trick is, when updating children of a node you can put "the_key" with slash "/" plus the field that you want to update, in this case "username"

```
DatabaseReference postDbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("posts");

Map<String, Object> updateValues = new HashMap<String, Object>();
String oldUserName = "userA";
String newUserName = "userA new";

postDbRef.orderByChild("username")
   .equalTo(oldUserName)
   .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        updateValues.put(childSnapshot.getKey()+"/username", newUsername);
                    }

                    postDbRef.updateChildren(updateValues);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
    });
;
```

For improving performance, I'm suggesting to add ".indexOn" in your database rule. Something like this :

```
"posts": {
  ".indexOn": ["username"]
},
```